# Fluxxor pass flux object to the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I want to pass flux object to a child component instead a parent.parent component is inside render function. there I dont wanna pass fluxxor instance .

I wanna something like this . Is it possible ?

```
 var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                <Application flux={flux} />

        );
    }

});
```

I am using [Fluxxor](http://fluxxor.com/) for fluxx

Answer (score 0):

With Fluxxor, if you need access to Flux from a child component, you don't need to pass it down in a prop, instead you use the FluxMixin:

```
var FluxMixin = Fluxxor.FluxMixin(React);

var Application = React.createClass({
  mixins: [FluxMixin],
  someFunction: function() {
     var flux = this.getFlux(); // getFlux is available due to mixin
  }
  //...
};
```

This is all described in detail here: http://fluxxor.com/guides/quick-start.html